# Conflict between Global.asx and CSS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, css, global-asax

I need to restrict multiple users from logging into my system. I am using Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest event in global.asax to see if anybody is logged in. It works really well.

But CSS is not loading and the screen looks horrible. If I comment out the code in that event, the page renders perfectly...

What am I missing? What does Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest has anything to do with CSS??

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: What are you doing in `Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest` please post some code, it is more likely your code is causing the problem, hence it works when you comment out YOUR code.

Comment: I second Ben's recommendation that some context be provided. If you replace your existing code with some no-operation type code (dummy assignments, for example) does the CSS problem still occur?

Comment: Here is the code that's in my Global.asax file

protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["user"] != null) // e.g. this is after an initial logon
        {
            string sKey = (string)Session["user"];
            string sUser = (string)HttpContext.Current.Cache[sKey];
        }
    }

If I comment out the code inside this, it's working. If I unComment it, CSS is not loading. I want this function to be executed everytime a page is requested so that I could restrict number of users logged in. Let me try Dug's recommendation

Answer (score 2):

Move your css to a folder that contains the following web.config

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Then change your header text to point to the new css location.  If you ar using themes simply add the web.config file to you theme folder.

**Note:** This overrides your security settings and allows everyone access to the folder containing the additional web.config file. This also includes sub folders

Comment: Its fixed now... Had to use a Web.Config for CSS and JavaScript folder...

Thanks a lot for the help guys...